# Slide Carousel on Click With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I'm having problems sliding my carousel div which has 500% width and has a "previous" and "next" arrow. I have 5 inner divs, each inner div includes an image and some text, occupies 20% of the main container, and I want to slide them back and forth (from left to right) when the user clicks on the arrows.

The problem I'm having is that I can only get the JS to slide one image forward and one back but when I click on the "next" arrow again it doesn't move to the next slide.

*Basically just look at my JS code that will fix the entire problem!

Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
 <div id="carouselslider">

   <div id="carouseldiv1">
     <img id="carouselimg1" src="images/offer1.jpg">
     <div 
 id="offertextbox"><h4>Logo Designs</h4><p>We offer a wide range of logo 
 designs to represent your company and online image. Ranging from modern, to 
 conservative logos all the while striving for top notch results for you.</p> 
     </div>
   </div>    
   <div id="carouseldiv2">
     <img id="carouselimg2" src="images/offer2.jpg">
     <div 
 id="offertextbox"><h4>Logo Designs</h4><p>We offer a wide range of logo 
 designs to represent your company and online image. Ranging from modern, to 
 conservative logos all the while striving for top notch results for you.</p> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="carouseldiv3">
     <img id="carouselimg3" src="images/offer3.jpg">
     <div 
 id="offertextbox"><h4>Logo Designs</h4><p>We offer a wide range of logo 
 designs to represent your company and online image. Ranging from modern, to 
 conservative logos all the while striving for top notch results for you.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="carouseldiv4">
     <img id="carouselimg4" src="images/offer4.jpg">
     <div 
 id="offertextbox"><h4>Logo Designs</h4><p>We offer a wide range of logo 
 designs to represent your company and online image. Ranging from modern, to 
 conservative logos all the while striving for top notch results for you.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="carouseldiv5">
     <img id="carouselimg5" src="images/offer5.jpg">
     <div 
id="offertextbox"><h4>Logo Designs</h4><p>We offer a wide range of logo 
designs to represent your company and online image. Ranging from modern, to 
conservative logos all the while striving for top notch results for you.</p> 
     </div>
  </div>

  <div>      <!--Arrow to slide next and previous (linked to JS below)-->
    <i onclick="slideleft()" class="fa leftarr">&#xf104;</i>
    <i onclick="slideright()" class="fa rightarr">&#xf105;</i>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#carouselslider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#carouseldiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#carouseldiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#carouseldiv3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
} 
#carouseldiv4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#carouseldiv5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

JS:

```js
function slideright() {
  if(document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = "0%")
  {
    var push = "-100%";
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = "-100%")
  {
    var push = "-200%";        
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = "-200%")
  {
    var push = "-300%";        
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = "-300%")
  {
    var push = "-400%";        
  }
  document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = push; 
}
```

Comment: The first `</div>` in `</div><i></i><i></i></div>` near the end should be a **`<div>`**.

Comment: no it had nothing to do with that, i think i just missed added a / when pasting the code here. thx anyways man!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so to use a framework all you have to do is link to it in the header section of your html file. In this instance I would suggest bootstrap 4.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
```

Once you have added it to your head section your should have access to the bootstrap classes. What you will be using is a bootstrap carousel example as such aswell as the link to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) and further [examples](http://%3Cdiv%20id=%22demo%22%20class=%22carousel%20slide%22%20data-ride=%22carousel%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Indicators%20--%3E%20%20%20%3Cul%20class=%22carousel-indicators%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20data-target=%22#demo%22%20data-slide-to=%220%22%20class=%22active%22%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20data-target=%22#demo%22%20data-slide-to=%221%22%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20data-target=%22#demo%22%20data-slide-to=%222%22%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20The%20slideshow%20--%3E%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22carousel-inner%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22carousel-item%20active%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22la.jpg%22%20alt=%22Los%20Angeles%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22carousel-item%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22chicago.jpg%22%20alt=%22Chicago%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22carousel-item%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22ny.jpg%22%20alt=%22New%20York%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Left%20and%20right%20controls%20--%3E%20%20%20%3Ca%20class=%22carousel-control-prev%22%20href=%22#demo%22%20data-slide=%22prev%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22carousel-control-prev-icon%22%3E%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%3C/a%3E%20%20%20%3Ca%20class=%22carousel-control-next%22%20href=%22#demo%22%20data-slide=%22next%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class=%22carousel-control-next-icon%22%3E%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%3C/a%3E%20%20%3C/div%3E):

```
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I think i can use a whatever, not limited i dont think. Never used one before though. Can you show me how to?

Comment: Thanks for that but i have already seen this in w3schools site. The reason i specifically didn't use that is because it messes up my entire html layout and it is too much work to fix a whoe page of layout. Do you know sufficient JS to fix the script so it works properly? Thanks

Comment: I fixed the forward clicking problem, but not for the previous clicking...

Comment: thougt you were gonna use bootstrap? mind showing what your index file looks like?

Comment: its ok man i found it! Can you accept my answer please?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys so after hours of working on my code i finally found the solution!
Here is the JS for reference for others who need this solution.

```
//Carousel Sliders JS
var x = 0;

function slideright() {

    if(x != -400)
    {
        x = x -100;
        document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = x+"%";
    }
}


function slideleft() {

    if(x != 0)
    {    
        x = x + 100;
        document.getElementById("carouselslider").style.left = x+"%";
    }
}
```